# How to click an individual part of 'canvas' in selenium?

Tags: selenium

I am trying to click a specific part i.e first part(19.9%) of image but its always clicking any of the value which are after 14.3%. Please check the image.[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoUlM.png]]

The code is:

```
<div class="tvimagesContainer" style="width: 80px; height: 241px;">
<canvas class="tabCanvas tab-widget" width="71" height="213" style="display: block; width: 80px; height: 237px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

I tried with following:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='tabZoneId21']/div/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/canvas")
WebElement wbcanvas;



Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            Action drawAction = builder.moveToElement(wbcanvas, 213/12,10).// 
                      .click()
                      .build();
            drawAction.perform();
```

In place of 213/12,10 put different values and tried but its clicking every time on the middle part of image.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it like following, this will click the one above of the middle. You can change the value`(213/12)`. If you want to click below fields then you need to change y to value below 0 :

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(wbcanvas).moveByOffset(0, (213/12)).click().build();
actions.perform();
```

Comment: Its showing red line under drawAction, i try to solve it and let you know.

Comment: Change it to the actions :) sorry missed that part.